# How does SqlDataReader determine whether to set a column to ReadOnly when filling a DataTable?

Tags: .net, sql-server, datatable, sqldatareader

I'm calling `dataTable.Load(sqlDataReader)` and 2 of columns are getting set to `ReadOnly` in the dataTable automatically. The rest of the columns are editable. I know I can edit this property, but I was wondering how it determines what to set to `ReadOnly`.

One of the columns is the primary key of the table and the other is a `Bit`. The `Bit` column has a default constraint in SQL Server, but that is all. The query I'm using to call it is converting the column to an `INT`. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can edit my SQL query to make a column read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kind of answered your own question by specifying the column details.

My assumption is that the DataTable is created in such a manner as to being able to update, insert, delete a row/column etc.  So anything that is handled by a resource other than the DataTable or is calculated is probably read only.

So Primary Key column is likely a IDENTITY column meaning the database assigns the key, meaning you do NOT want to add your own value!  And therefore is marked as read only.

The next is probably not because there is a default on the column.  Because technically you are not including the bit column but you are including a calculated column based on the bit column.  So the column you are including doesn't actually exist in the underlying table and as such .net wouldn't be able to alter the data in the column.....

Comment: Yeah, I was actually OK with it making the PK readonly but I don't want converted values to be readonly automatically. I converted my varchars to varchars and watched them become readonly, so I guess that's it. You wouldn't happen to know of a way to prevent that would you?

Comment: I guess the question is why are you converting?  Then for not being read only, how would you map your conversion back to update/insert the underlying table?  That second question is why they are being marked as readonly you will have to implement custom business logic and update/insert commands.

Comment: I was converting it because the Bit was making it become a checkbox in the DataGrid and that wasn't what I was looking for. It ended up not working with my update/insert on the round trip. I ended up going a different route with my approach to give me more control.